# RewriteRule violates while switching from https to http

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I write a lot of **RewriteRule** in my `.htaccess` file , but problem occurs when I switch from **https** to **http** pages; it does not follow these rules

**NOTE :** everything working fine on localhost ,  issues are on server <---- **UPDATE**

Here is my [website](http://www.charityrummage.com) , currently all links display as per **RewriteRule***

for  e.g. **about us** page link display as

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/about
```

**BUT**

if I am at [`login page`](https://www.charityrummage.com/login) ( which is on `https` ) and click on **about us** page then it turns into below.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/about?slug=about_us
```

or if I click on any category on left panel then it comes as

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/auction/category/1?cid=1
```

**Note :**  even mouse hovering on pages display rewrite link

below is `.htaccess` file with needed information.

```
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^auction/category/([0-9]+)/?$ bids.php?cid=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [NC]

# static pages
RewriteRule ^about/?$ page.php?slug=about_us [NC]

# Rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /do_login.php     
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# traffic to http:// except some pages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/login|/do_login.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

*Note :* [`Here`](http://pastebin.com/YPiehZq1) is complete `.htaccess` file

Please tell me where I am wrong/missing ?

I Also have few more confusion

- If i change the case of rewrite URL ( **Login or lOgin or logiN** )  then it gives error?
- Is it good practice to write **[NC,L]** with all `RewriteRule`?
- Exactly when I should write  **[QSA]** ?

---

## UPDATE

After suggestions from all answers, **changing in `RewriteRule` almost fixed all issue** but now there is one last issue.

- `/login` URL always changed into `/login.php`.

below is my updated **.htaccess**

```
IndexIgnore *
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks

#mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.%{HTTP_HOST} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# minimize the css on all http:// pages
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /csszip.php?file=$1.css [L]
</IfModule>

#switch over http to https

# Rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/login|/do_login)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# traffic to http:// except some pages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/login|/do_login)\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [NC]
# ...many other rules...with [NC] falg

RewriteRule ^auction/category/([^/.]+)/?$ bids.php?cid=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ page.php?slug=about_us [NC]
# ...many more rules.... with [NC] flag
```

Comment: In your login page if i mouse hover the about link it displays https: //www.charityrummage.com/about, isnt the link to about us page should be in http ??

Comment: yes mouse hover display right link but if you click on this then see the link?

Comment: QSA is only meaningful when you are changing the query string (by using a ? in your substitution) and you want to append the old string.

Don't append NC,L to every rule.  If you want it case insensitive, use NC. In htaccess, using L causes the current round of processing to end with the current substitution -- either your htaccess depends on that or it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## HTTPS suggestion

For your HTTPS issue I would match on port or HTTPS as there are known apache problems relating to the HTTPS tag.

To cover this match on both (as shown in your edited answer)

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on

##REWRITE RULE

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = on

##REWRITE RULE
```

A valid point is also that `%{REQUEST_URI}` isn't affected by any substitutions.

The way you are using it at the moment, if any rule matches you will send them to the original url (before any substitution started).

If you want to take the url after and substition and matching use `$1`

---

Answers to your **further questions**:

## If I change the case of rewrite URL then it gives error?

This is because your `[NC]` isn't on the rewrite cond for the HTTPS section of your .htaccess

You match `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login [OR]` this is only looking for lower case login, if you want to accept uppercase login append NC.

---

## Is it good practice to write [NC,L] with all RewriteRule?

No, it depends what you want to do `[NC]` says don't match case on this rule, if you don't want to match case on that **rule** (or **condition**) then add it.

Not matching the case with `[NC]` means site.com/login.php = sYte.cOm/LoGin.PHP

`[L]` means if this is true, stop processing everything

---

## Exactly when I should write [QSA] ?

QSA applies when you have a ? in your substitution and you want to append toe old string to the new URL

Consider the following rule:

```
RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

With the `[QSA]` flag, a request for `/pages/123?one=two` will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123&one=two`. Without the [QSA] flag, that same request will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123` - that is, the existing query string will be **discarded**.

Do use QSA if you want to **keep** any additional get arguments.

---

Another **further question**

## /login URL always changed into /login.php

The only way for this to happen is if you have a redirect `[R=301]` somewhere in your code, the only place I can see that is this section:

```
# Rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/login|/do_login)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Where this will **only** match the following URL's

.php, /login.php, /do_login.php

I believe the culprit is as I outlined in the first response with `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Your code essentially says, if these conditions are met, send them to **https://theurltheywentto**, which is not what you want to do, you want to send them to /login.

Have you tried using (as mentioned in my https section)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login [R=301,L]
```

Or perhaps (if you have /do_login) and other options

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where test.com/do_login.php will become https://test.com/do_login

How about you try:

```
# Rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/login|/do_login)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. Will you please describe more on `HTTPS suggestion` point

Comment: even i changed `[OR]` lines with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/login|/do_login.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]` but still website.com/ **Login** gives error.

Comment: You want NC on the cond, not the rule

Comment: I have updated my Code. many issues has been fixed after your suggestion, now only 1 issue is there. please have a look on my update.

Comment: i tried you given solution but it gives **This webpage has a redirect loop**  error. and second Thing:  there are few more pages to be display on `https` ( added in | condition )  so `https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login` will not be helpful.

Comment: yes, I did not write other pages name due to security concern. i write only essential code part.

Comment: Please [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16831/discussion-between-pez-cuckow-and-diecho)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. but still there is something lacking. but anyways you did a great job. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be of your help

[.htaccess redirect https to http not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980324/htaccess-redirect-https-to-http-not-working)

and for last question this might be of your help

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html and

http://www.addedbytes.com/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2/png/

**EDIT:**
You can try  using

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
```

For detail

Please see this link, someone had similar problem. Please see second reply of the post

http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3228459.htm

Comment: No,Using port is bad idea. instead of this used both conditions together:`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this by creating the domain alias

You can't do it within `.htaccess`, but within a `http.conf` `<VirtualHost>` section you can use the [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) and [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) directives to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion over /about is due to redirecting to %{REQUEST_URI}, which isn't changed as you make substitutions.  Capture the URI and use $1 if you don't really want the URI as it started uring this round of rewrite processing.