# Can .htaccess sanity check?

Tags: .htaccess

I need a quick review of my updated .htaccess file please:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirects errors to 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Redirect index.php to site root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]

# Unless directory remove slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

It's fairly straight forward.

> The first is a 404 redirect.
>   The second redirects www.mysite.com/index.php to www.mysite.com
>   The third removes slashes.
>   The fourth removes the .php extension.
>   The fifth resolves php.

Could someone cast an eye over this and give my code a quick sanity check please.

Comment: I don't know what that means? I'm new here :/

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it useful! Voting to close of off topic is because it may not be the style of question that is accepted at stack overflow (you don't address a direct issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below may make more sense at the top as you are redirecting the user and they will go through all of the .htaccess file again.

What you're actually doing here is if any of these are `true` you are telling the browser to go and load the website again from a different url "`[R=301]`".

```
# Redirect index.php to site root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Your other redirects are in a sensible order, if not a directory drop the slash, if a php drop the .php then resolve anything without a slash.

Note this will result in a quite a few redirects if a user visits your website at certain url's for example `mysite.com/cake.php/` (which doesn't exist)

`mysite.com/cake.php/` => `mysite.com/cake.php`
 `mysite.com/cake.php` => `mysite.com/cake`
 `mysite.com/cake` => `http://www.mysite.com/cake`
 `http://www.mysite.com/cake` resolves to `http://www.mysite.com/cake.php` - doesn't exist
 `404` => `http://www.mysite.com/404.php`
 `http://www.mysite.com/404.php` => `http://www.mysite.com/404`

Though in summary it does what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks, I've repositioned it. Is the rest of the code ok? I've been through countless pages in SO and think it will do what I want, I'd just like someone with more experience than me to have a quick look over it. Thank you :)

Comment: @Pez Cuckow why we  use `[NC]` flag with `RewriteCond` and  `ReWriteRule`both?

Comment: @diEcho this is taken from his code, I guess he want's to be REALLY sure it's not case sensitive ;-)

Comment: @PezCuckow yes but why we use two times? just a query

Comment: @PezCuckow I don't think it has a purpose, I've removed from my answer above, it'll have very minor overhead

Comment: @Pez Cuckow you have a good hand with `.htaccess` problems. Will you please go through my Bounty question [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400792/rewriterule-violates-while-switching-from-https-to-http)