# htacess redirect all pages to www except checkout page

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a website with ssl which works on only the non www version. Is it possible to redirect all url to www version except the checkout page using htacess and to add the https:// on the checkout page

Thanks

Comment: yes sure. seeI have asked same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400792/rewriterule-violates-while-switching-from-https-to-http) few days back.

Comment: Look up mod_rewrite 

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I think the real issue here is why doesnt youre ssl work with www? Post more about your server config and maybe we can help you fix that

Comment: the site has an ssl that worked only on non www version, everything i try just ends up in redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your checkout page is at `https://domain.com/checkout.php`

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect non-www hostname to www hostname, but not /checkout.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?checkout.php http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if checkout.php, redirect if not HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?checkout.php https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```